# A word for distracting a person's attention from their numbness or lack of sensitivity

Tags: single-word-requests

Numbness is the absence of physical sensation. What single word might be used for "distracting" from it, for diverting a person's attention from their numbness or lack of sensitivity?

> - Bert found that stroking his elbow was the best way of ____ himself from his numbness.
> - Bert winked at her to ____ her from her numbness.

Comment: This is unclear. It almost sounds as if you want a word to indicate "the best way of  numbing himself from his numbness."

Comment: I suppose one might use the verb "awake".

Comment: @Cascable. Indeed. It's for in a psychological novel. I've upticked your comment.

Comment: What's wrong with your own *distracting* or *diverting* that would make a different word better?

Answer (score 1):

Help to **[ignore](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ignore)**

- Bert found that stroking his elbow best helped him ignore his numbness.
- Bert winked at her to help her ignore her numbness.

Obviously this can't be directly substituted for "distract", but I thought I'd put it forward as an option. I'll remove my answer if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: This is a good answer. Perhaps _ignore_ is not the word I'll end up with, but it captures very well the vagueness and contradictoriness of the idea of having one's mind taken off of something it wasn't consciously paying much attention to in the first place.

Comment: Why this is upvoted is beyond me. Not only is it a poor choice of words, but it also doesn't suit the two sentences OP provided.

Comment: @AleksandrH In what way is this a poor choice of words? Try to be specific.

Comment: @AleksandrH - It doesn't read well, and in the first sentence in particular it's clunky, but the connotations and vagueness and contradictoriness are good. I am looking to evoke a mental state. Numbed from numbness? What might that even mean? Distracted from numbness without actually focusing on anything? We can't define this exactly or "properly", but we can have a vague understanding, which is the point. If you can suggest a word or phrase that you think does the job better, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

How about ***rouse***?  Per the Oxford Dictionaries:

> ***[rouse](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rouse)***
>
> **VERB**
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1. Cause to stop sleeping.
>
>    *‘she was roused from a deep sleep by a hand on her shoulder’*
>
>    1.1 [*no object*] Cease to sleep or to be inactive; wake up.
>
>    *‘she roused and looked around’*
>
>    1.2 Bring out of inactivity.
>
>    *‘once the enemy camp was roused, they would move on the castle’*
>        *‘she'd just stay a few more minutes, then rouse herself and go back’*
>
>    1.3 Startle (game) from a lair or cover.
> 2. Make angry or excited.
>
>    *‘the crowds were roused to fever pitch by the drama of the race’*
>
>    2.1 Give rise to (an emotion or feeling)
>
>    *‘his evasiveness roused my curiosity’*

Most of these definitions apply, but I think 1.2 especially works.

For a sense of a more permanent end to the numbness, perhaps ***cure*** and/or ***remedy*** could work?  Again, from the Oxford Dictionaries:

> ***[cure](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cure)***
>
> **VERB**
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1. Relieve (a person or animal) of the symptoms of a disease or condition.
>
> *‘he was cured of the disease’*
>
> 1.1 Eliminate (a disease or condition) with medical treatment.
>
> *‘this technology could be used to cure diabetes’*
>
> 1.2 Solve (a problem)
>
> *‘a bid to trace and cure the gearbox problems’*

Which would be:

> Bert found that stroking his elbow was the best way of ***curing*** his numbness.
>
> Bert winked at her to ***cure*** her from her numbness.

or for *remedy*:

> ***[remedy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/remedy)***
>
> **NOUN**
>
> 1. A medicine or treatment for a disease or injury.
>
>    *‘herbal remedies for aches and pains’*
>
>    1.1 A means of counteracting or eliminating something undesirable.
>
>    *‘shopping became a remedy for personal problems’*
>
>    1.2 A means of legal reparation.
>
>    *‘compensation is available as a remedy against governmental institutions’*
>
> **VERB**
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> Set right (an undesirable situation)
>
> *‘money will be given to remedy the poor funding of nurseries’*

which would give you:

> Bert found that stroking his elbow was the best way to ***remedy*** himself of his numbness.
>
> Bert winked at her as a ***remedy*** to her numbness.

Comment: This would be good if I needed to denote the reversal or ending of numbness.

Comment: Are you looking for a permanent end to the numbness?  Or just a temporary bit of respite?  Your first sentence would seem to suggest the latter, in which case I think ***rouse*** would work really well: _Bert found that stroking his elbow was the best way of **rousing** himself from his numbness._  and _Bert winked at her to **rouse** her from her numbness._  If you're looking for a more permanent end to the numbness, maybe ***remedy*** or ***cure***?  I'll add that to the answer...

Comment: @ruffle -- I've added ***remedy*** and ***cure*** as possible answers.

Comment: Thanks. Just temporary respite but which may continue for a while. I'm not trying to get them to a state that's opposite to numbness but one where their minds are taken off it. I'm trying to be vague, even contradictory, to get the reader to ponder.

Comment: Rouse is what I originally came here to put. It's probably the best option here.

Comment: @ruffle -- Perhaps _taking a vacation_ from their numbness might work?  Or maybe _pause_?  (As in _Bert found that stroking his elbow was the best way to **pause** his numbness._)